# Can´t access localhost on mobile via domain name, only ip (xampp)

Tags: mobile, xampp, localhost, wifi

Tried it all so far

In hosts file: my_IP example.com
127.0.0.1    example.com

In vhosts:

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin mail@mail.ma
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com

I can access localhost via IP on mobile/wi-fi, but not via example.com

I can access example.com via the other desktop in the network

Router - to Server PC where xampp is running (ethernet)

```
   - to Other Desktop (ethernet)
```

From Router to mobile (wifi)

Need to access Server PC via mobile using the domain name